# Adicionar o intervalo dos anos a uma coluna

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
formula_one <- tibble(
       driver_name = c("Carlo Abate",
                       "George Abecassis","Kenny Acheson","Andrea de Adamich",
                       "Philippe Adams","Walt Ader","Kurt Adolff","Fred Agabashian",
                       "Kurt Ahrens Jr."),
       nationality = c("Italy","United Kingdom",
                       "United Kingdom","Italy","Belgium","United States",
                       "West Germany","United States","West Germany"),
  seasons_competed = c("1962 – 1963","1951 – 1952",
                       "1983 , 1985","1968 , 1970 – 1973","1994","1950",
                       "1953","1950 – 1957","1966 – 1969")
)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed  
  <chr>             <chr>          <chr>             
1 Carlo Abate       Italy          1962 – 1963       
2 George Abecassis  United Kingdom 1951 – 1952       
3 Kenny Acheson     United Kingdom 1983 , 1985       
4 Andrea de Adamich Italy          1968 , 1970 – 1973
5 Philippe Adams    Belgium        1994              
6 Walt Ader         United States  1950              
7 Kurt Adolff       West Germany   1953              
8 Fred Agabashian   United States  1950 – 1957       
9 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany   1966 – 1969
```

Minha intenção é deixar a base no formato tidy.

Fiz o seguinte:

- usei `separate_rows()` para separar as linhas pela vírgula,
- filtrei apenas os que continham o padrão `DDDD - DDDD`
- usei `separate_rows()` novamente, dessa vez para separar as linhas pelo hífen,
- converti a coluna "seasons_competed" para o formato numérico.

```
formula_one_subset <- 
formula_one %>% 
  separate_rows(seasons_competed, sep = " , ") %>% 
  filter(str_detect(seasons_competed, pattern = "[0-9]{4} – [0-9]{4}")) %>% 
  separate_rows(seasons_competed, sep = " – ") %>% 
  mutate(seasons_competed = as.integer(seasons_competed))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
   driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed
   <chr>             <chr>                     <int>
 1 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1962
 2 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1963
 3 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1951
 4 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1952
 5 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1970
 6 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1973
 7 Fred Agabashian   United States              1950
 8 Fred Agabashian   United States              1957
 9 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1966
10 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1969
```

A partir daqui não consigo avançar.
Imaginei que a função `complete()` resolveria. Mas não deu certo:

```
  formula_one_subset %>% 
  complete(seasons_competed = min(formula_one_subset$seasons_competed):max(formula_one_subset$seasons_competed)) %>% 
  print(n=Inf)

A tibble: 24 x 3
   seasons_competed driver_name       nationality   
              <int> <chr>             <chr>         
 1             1950 Fred Agabashian   United States 
 2             1951 George Abecassis  United Kingdom
 3             1952 George Abecassis  United Kingdom
 4             1953 NA                NA            
 5             1954 NA                NA            
 6             1955 NA                NA            
 7             1956 NA                NA            
 8             1957 Fred Agabashian   United States 
 9             1958 NA                NA            
10             1959 NA                NA            
11             1960 NA                NA            
12             1961 NA                NA            
13             1962 Carlo Abate       Italy         
14             1963 Carlo Abate       Italy         
15             1964 NA                NA            
16             1965 NA                NA            
17             1966 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany  
18             1967 NA                NA            
19             1968 NA                NA            
20             1969 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany  
21             1970 Andrea de Adamich Italy         
22             1971 NA                NA            
23             1972 NA                NA            
24             1973 Andrea de Adamich Italy
```

No entanto, isto não dá certo por uma série de motivos.

"Fred Agabashian" competiu de 1950 a 1957 e isto não está na tabela gerada
Pensei que eu poderia usar `fill()` para preencer os NA da coluna "driver_name". Mas também não dá certo.
Para ficar em um exemplo: "Carlo Abate" só competiu os anos de 1962 e 1963. No entant, se eu uso `fill()` para preencher em qualquer dos dois sentidos, vou incorrer em erro.

Em suma, o que esperaria obter seria:

```
 A tibble: 20 x 3
   driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed
   <chr>             <chr>                     <int>
 1 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1962
 2 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1963
 3 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1951
 4 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1952
 5 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1970
 6 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1971
 7 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1972
 8 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1973
 9 Fred Agabashian   United States              1950
10 Fred Agabashian   United States              1951
11 Fred Agabashian   United States              1952
12 Fred Agabashian   United States              1953
13 Fred Agabashian   United States              1954
14 Fred Agabashian   United States              1955
15 Fred Agabashian   United States              1956
16 Fred Agabashian   United States              1957
17 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1966
18 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1967
19 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1968
20 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1969
```

Aliás, o caminho está correto ou a abordagem poderia ter sido outra desde o início (uma que não passasse, por exemplo, pelo `separate_rows()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma abordagem diferente: usar `gsub` para formar uma *string* a ser avaliada como vetor com `eval`. Um exemplo da ideia:

```
st <- "1, 3-5, 7-9, 11"

st.v <- gsub("-", ":", sub("(.*)", "c(\\1)", st))

st.v
#> [1] "c(1, 3:5, 7:9, 11)"

eval(parse(text = st.v)) # ou eval(str2expression(st.v))
#> [1]  1  3  4  5  7  8  9 11
```

Com seus dados, usando `tidyverse` para avaliar por nome e nacionalidade:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

formula_one %>%
  group_by(driver_name, nationality) %>%
  expand(season = as.integer(eval(parse(text = gsub("–", ":", sub("(.*)", "c(\\1)", seasons_competed))))))
#> # A tibble: 26 × 3
#> # Groups:   driver_name, nationality [9]
#>    driver_name       nationality   season
#>    <chr>             <chr>          <int>
#>  1 Andrea de Adamich Italy           1968
#>  2 Andrea de Adamich Italy           1970
#>  3 Andrea de Adamich Italy           1971
#>  4 Andrea de Adamich Italy           1972
#>  5 Andrea de Adamich Italy           1973
#>  6 Carlo Abate       Italy           1962
#>  7 Carlo Abate       Italy           1963
#>  8 Fred Agabashian   United States   1950
#>  9 Fred Agabashian   United States   1951
#> 10 Fred Agabashian   United States   1952
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

Ou com `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(formula_one)[,
  .(season = as.integer(eval(parse(text = gsub("–", ":", sub("(.*)", "c(\\1)", seasons_competed)))))),
  .(driver_name, nationality)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver transformando o dataset para o formato lista e usando `purrr::map()` para aplicar as funções `complete()` e `fill()` a cada elemento da lista.

No entanto, primeiro foi preciso fazer uma adaptação.

Me dei conta que não bastava separar as linhas do dataset com os intervalos. Também é necessário criar um subset para os anos individuais.

Assim: criei um subset para os anos individuais:

```
formula_one_subset_individuais <- formula_one %>% 
  separate_rows(seasons_competed, sep = " , ") %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(seasons_competed, pattern = " – ")) %>% 
  mutate(seasons_competed = as.integer(seasons_competed))


# A tibble: 6 x 3
  driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed
  <chr>             <chr>                     <int>
1 Kenny Acheson     United Kingdom             1983
2 Kenny Acheson     United Kingdom             1985
3 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1968
4 Philippe Adams    Belgium                    1994
5 Walt Ader         United States              1950
6 Kurt Adolff       West Germany               1953
```

E outro para os intervalos:

```
formula_one_subset_intervalos <- formula_one %>% 
  separate_rows(seasons_competed, sep = " , ") %>% 
  filter(str_detect(seasons_competed, pattern = " – ")) %>% 
  separate_rows(seasons_competed, sep = " – ") %>% 
  mutate(seasons_competed = as.integer(seasons_competed))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed
   <chr>             <chr>                     <int>
 1 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1962
 2 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1963
 3 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1951
 4 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1952
 5 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1970
 6 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1973
 7 Fred Agabashian   United States              1950
 8 Fred Agabashian   United States              1957
 9 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1966
10 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1969
```

Converti o subset de intervalos em lista:

```
formula_one_subset_intervalos_lista <- split(formula_one_subset_intervalos, formula_one_subset_intervalos$driver_name)

$`Andrea de Adamich`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  driver_name       nationality seasons_competed
  <chr>             <chr>                  <int>
1 Andrea de Adamich Italy                   1970
2 Andrea de Adamich Italy                   1973

$`Carlo Abate`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  driver_name nationality seasons_competed
  <chr>       <chr>                  <int>
1 Carlo Abate Italy                   1962
2 Carlo Abate Italy                   1963

$`Fred Agabashian`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  driver_name     nationality   seasons_competed
  <chr>           <chr>                    <int>
1 Fred Agabashian United States             1950
2 Fred Agabashian United States             1957

$`George Abecassis`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  driver_name      nationality    seasons_competed
  <chr>            <chr>                     <int>
1 George Abecassis United Kingdom             1951
2 George Abecassis United Kingdom             1952

$`Kurt Ahrens Jr.`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  driver_name     nationality  seasons_competed
  <chr>           <chr>                   <int>
1 Kurt Ahrens Jr. West Germany             1966
2 Kurt Ahrens Jr. West Germany             1969
```

E com a função `map()` apliquei as funções `complete()` e `fill()`.
Por fim, reconverti a lista em dataframe com a função `map_df()`:

```
formula_one_subset_intervalos_df <- formula_one_subset_intervalos_lista %>% 
  map(~complete(.x, seasons_competed = min(seasons_competed):max(seasons_competed))) %>% 
  map(~fill(.x, everything())) %>% 
  map_df(~.x)


# A tibble: 20 x 3
   seasons_competed driver_name       nationality   
              <int> <chr>             <chr>         
 1             1970 Andrea de Adamich Italy         
 2             1971 Andrea de Adamich Italy         
 3             1972 Andrea de Adamich Italy         
 4             1973 Andrea de Adamich Italy         
 5             1962 Carlo Abate       Italy         
 6             1963 Carlo Abate       Italy         
 7             1950 Fred Agabashian   United States 
 8             1951 Fred Agabashian   United States 
 9             1952 Fred Agabashian   United States 
10             1953 Fred Agabashian   United States 
11             1954 Fred Agabashian   United States 
12             1955 Fred Agabashian   United States 
13             1956 Fred Agabashian   United States 
14             1957 Fred Agabashian   United States 
15             1951 George Abecassis  United Kingdom
16             1952 George Abecassis  United Kingdom
17             1966 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany  
18             1967 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany  
19             1968 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany  
20             1969 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany
```

Finalmente, juntei com o dataset que continha os anos isolados:

```
formula_one_final <- bind_rows(formula_one_subset_individuais, formula_one_subset_intervalos_df) %>% 
  arrange(driver_name)

# A tibble: 26 x 3
   driver_name       nationality   seasons_competed
   <chr>             <chr>                    <int>
 1 Andrea de Adamich Italy                     1968
 2 Andrea de Adamich Italy                     1970
 3 Andrea de Adamich Italy                     1971
 4 Andrea de Adamich Italy                     1972
 5 Andrea de Adamich Italy                     1973
 6 Carlo Abate       Italy                     1962
 7 Carlo Abate       Italy                     1963
 8 Fred Agabashian   United States             1950
 9 Fred Agabashian   United States             1951
10 Fred Agabashian   United States             1952
```

Comparando o original com o modificado, vê-se que todos os anos estão devidamente preenchidos:

## Original

```
formula_one

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed  
  <chr>             <chr>          <chr>             
1 Carlo Abate       Italy          1962 – 1963       
2 George Abecassis  United Kingdom 1951 – 1952       
3 Kenny Acheson     United Kingdom 1983 , 1985       
4 Andrea de Adamich Italy          1968 , 1970 – 1973
5 Philippe Adams    Belgium        1994              
6 Walt Ader         United States  1950              
7 Kurt Adolff       West Germany   1953              
8 Fred Agabashian   United States  1950 – 1957       
9 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany   1966 – 1969
```

## Final

```
formula_one_final %>% 
  print(n = Inf)

# A tibble: 26 x 3
   driver_name       nationality    seasons_competed
   <chr>             <chr>                     <int>
 1 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1968
 2 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1970
 3 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1971
 4 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1972
 5 Andrea de Adamich Italy                      1973
 6 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1962
 7 Carlo Abate       Italy                      1963
 8 Fred Agabashian   United States              1950
 9 Fred Agabashian   United States              1951
10 Fred Agabashian   United States              1952
11 Fred Agabashian   United States              1953
12 Fred Agabashian   United States              1954
13 Fred Agabashian   United States              1955
14 Fred Agabashian   United States              1956
15 Fred Agabashian   United States              1957
16 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1951
17 George Abecassis  United Kingdom             1952
18 Kenny Acheson     United Kingdom             1983
19 Kenny Acheson     United Kingdom             1985
20 Kurt Adolff       West Germany               1953
21 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1966
22 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1967
23 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1968
24 Kurt Ahrens Jr.   West Germany               1969
25 Philippe Adams    Belgium                    1994
26 Walt Ader         United States              1950
```